# select gridview row after search

Tags: c#, gridview

Form 1 and 2

how do i auto select after i click search from another form ?
iam using C#. the textbox below only for store(check) i want the form 1 with gridview is selected 
my code below on form 2 :

[image]

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cari();
    }

public void cari()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, myConnection);
        try
        {
            ds.Tables.Clear();

            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from General.genre WHERE genre Like  '%"+textEdit1.Text.ToString()+"%' or code like '%"+textEdit1.Text+"%'";
            myConnection.Open();

          var  buka = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (buka.Read())
            {
                 textEdit2.Text = buka[1].ToString();

            }
            else 
                    {
                MessageBox.Show("type genre");
            }


          //  MessageBox.Show("kebaca");

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {


            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }

        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGrid.SelectedRows.Clear();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    if(YOUR CONDITION)
       row.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: whre do i input this code?
iam using gridview from devexpress though

Comment: at the end of cari() or where you already know which row(s) do you want to select

Comment: if there is no condition, than you dont need to specifiy a condition

Comment: all i want is when i type "DANCE" and click find
the form1 with gridview automatically select row with genre "DANCE"
but in the code i just use it to compare and store it in the texbox2 below.
and i dont the the code or syntax to change the selection row gridview in form 1 base on textbox1 in form 2..
thanks before

Comment: i cannot say where to paste it in, it is your app, your code. you have to find the row in the grid and select it with the code row.selected = true .

Comment: well, i make a new thread with a simple question
i trying using number to make the selection in other form.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38455664/how-do-i-alternate-gridview-selection-from-another-form?noredirect=1#comment64319857_38455664