# how do i alternate gridview selection from another form?

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

hello i want to ask how do we alternate selection row grid view at main form from another form just using text box and button

the picture and code  is in form 1 
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

and form 2 lets say only got text box and button
how do we can declare or use gridview data from form 1 in form 2 ?

Comment: What is "alternating gridview selection?  Do you mean to select and unselect the row?

Comment: as u can see when i type '3' in the textbox the focusrowhandle select on martial art (in one form). now what i want is i make another form with the same text box andbutton but when i type '2' the selection in form1 change become "BALLET",  its just i dont how to call or use the gridview in form1 to form 2

Comment: When and how do you open that second form?

Comment: well,just imagine the form 1 got another button to call form2.
like 
private void button2_click(object sender, event args){
form2 f2 = new form2()
f2.show()
}
and from there i dont know how to change the selection gridview in form 1. and form 2 only got textbox1 and button1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change Form2 so you can receive the gridView in the constructor :

```
public class Form2 : XtraForm
{
    private GridView grid;

    public Form2(GridView grid)
    {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    private void somebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.FocusedRowHandle = ...
    }
}
```

So when you open Form2 from Form1, you just send the gridView to the Form2 constructor :

```
someButtonOnForm1_Click(...)
{
    var form = new Form2(gridView1);
    form.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: first of all, well thanks it works when i input some number in grid.focusrowhandle = 2.  its just i dont know how it your code  work   like declare public Form2(GridView grid) and form.show(this) shouldnt it show another pop up of form 1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...?